InDesign - making an independent window that will stay open while making corrections in the document


var Widows_Report = new Window("dialog", "Let's Find Some Widows", undefined, {borderless: false, resizeable: false});
Widows_Report.orientation = "column";
Widows_Report.alignChildren = ["center", "top"];
Widows_Report.spacing = 10;
Widows_Report.margins = 16;

var panel1 = Widows_Report.add("panel", undefined, "Select the pages you want to search");
panel1.orientation = "column";
panel1.alignChildren = ["center", "center"];
panel1.spacing = 10;
panel1.margins = [10, 10, 9, 10];

var Page_Input = panel1.add("group");
Page_Input.orientation = "row";
Page_Input.alignChildren = ["center", "center"];
Page_Input.spacing = 10;
Page_Input.margins = 6;

var edittext1 = Page_Input.add('edittext', undefined, undefined, {name: "edittext1"});
edittext1.helpTip = "Enter the page number where you want the search to start";
edittext1.preferredSize.width = 45;
edittext1.preferredSize.height = 23;

var statictext1 = Page_Input.add("statictext", undefined, "Thru");
statictext1.preferredSize.width = 52;
statictext1.preferredSize.height = 17;
statictext1.justify = "center";

var edittext2 = Page_Input.add('edittext', undefined, undefined, {name: "edittext2"});
edittext2.helpTip = "Enter the page number where you want the search to end";
edittext2.preferredSize.width = 45;
edittext2.preferredSize.height = 23;

var group2 = Widows_Report.add("group");
group2.orientation = "column";
group2.alignChildren = ["left", "center"];
group2.spacing = 10;
group2.margins = 1;

var group3 = group2.add("group");
group3.orientation = "row";
group3.alignChildren = ["center", "top"];
group3.spacing = 10;
group3.margins = 0;

var button1 = group3.add("button", undefined, "Start");
button1.preferredSize.width = 68;

var button2 = group3.add("button", undefined, "Close");
button2.preferredSize.width = 61;

var group4 = group2.add("group");
group4.orientation = "column";
group4.alignChildren = ["center", "bottom"];
group4.spacing = 12;
group4.margins = 5;

// Start Button Click Event
button1.onClick = function() {
    var startPage = parseInt(edittext1.text);
    var endPage = parseInt(edittext2.text);

    // Validate page numbers
    if (isNaN(startPage) || isNaN(endPage) || startPage < 1 || startPage > app.activeDocument.pages.length || endPage < 1 || endPage > app.activeDocument.pages.length || startPage > endPage) {
        alert("Invalid page numbers. Please enter valid page numbers.");
    } else {
        var reportWidow = "HERE ARE YOUR RESULTS:\nThese pages have widows\n\n_______________________\n\n";         
                                              
        for (var i = startPage - 1; i < endPage; i++) {
            var page = app.activeDocument.pages[i];
            var textFrames = page.textFrames;
            for (var j = 0; j < textFrames.length; j++) {
                var textFrame = textFrames[j];
                var paragraphs = textFrame.paragraphs;
                for (var k = 0; k < paragraphs.length; k++) {
                    var paragraph = paragraphs[k];
                    var fontSize = paragraph.pointSize;
                    if (fontSize >= 9.5 && fontSize <= 11) {
                        var lastLine = paragraph.lines[-1];
                        if (lastLine && lastLine.words.length === 1) {
                            reportWidow += "PAGE " + (i + 1) + ",     PARAGRAPH " + (k + 1) + "\r";
                                reportWidow += lastLine.words[0].contents + "\r\r";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        if (reportWidow !== "HERE ARE YOUR RESULTS:\n") {
            alert(reportWidow);
        } else {
           alert("Congratulations, No Widows Were Found!");
        }
    }
};

// Close Button Click Event
button2.onClick = function() {
    Widows_Report.close();
};

Widows_Report.show();



I need the script to run, find any widows (paragraphs of text with only one word on the last line.) and then produce the search results inside of the original script window (instead of a second alert window which it does now). The search results are correct but I need to be able to look at the results (list of widows) while making corrections in the inDesign document.
2 main issues:
1 - Script Window Format - I can't figure out how to make the script window independent so that I can still work in inDesign while looking at the search results. Sometimes the results are a long list and I need to have the results shown until I close the window.
2 - Script Search Results - Right now, the script will run and properly find the widows, the problem is, the script produces a second alert window with the search results inside. The info that is produced is correct but I need it to show in the original script window (preferred) or instead of an alert window, show the search results in a new independent window that will stay open while making corrections.
Here is a shot of the search results as they appear now:
Current Search Results Alert Window
I have scoured this site, the web and even asked chat GPT for help. I admit that I am new to inDesign scripting so these 2 issues are probably basic stuff to most people.

I don't know what the script you mean. But it looks like the results (the list or widow lines) can be easy turned into a table (just a table in a new text frame) instead of the alert window. Probably it would be easiest modification. But it's need to see the actual script to be sure.

I just included the code, I forgot to attach it when I posted.

Note that if your goal is to prevent what I call stubs (and you call widows), this can be done automatically with GREP styles

Thanks @cybernetic.nomad. I'm not as familiar with GREP but know it is strong and can do this process (I'll look into it some more) but I want to roll this out with a package of scripts for my design department at work. We use scripts a lot so I'm keeping it familiar with everyone for now. Thanks

When you do find the time to look into it, know that you can apply GREP styles using a script, so the members of your team would just need to run said script to get rid of stubs.

Here is the quick simply solution. It saves the final message as a text file and opens it (supposedly in Notepad on Windows or TextEdit app on macOS) instead of the alert window.
Change the line:
alert(reportWidow);

with:
report(reportWidow);

And add at the end of the code the function:
function report(text) {
    var report_file = File(Folder.temp + '/widows.txt');
    report_file.encoding = 'utf-8';
    report_file.open('w');
    report_file.write(text);
    report_file.execute();
    report_file.close();
}


Another approach is to turn the dialog window into a palette and add to it the text area. Here is the changed code:
#target "InDesign"
#targetengine "session"

// "palette", not "dialog"
var Widows_Report = new Window("palette", "Let's Find Some Widows", undefined, {borderless: false, resizeable: false});
Widows_Report.orientation = "column";
Widows_Report.alignChildren = ["center", "top"];
Widows_Report.spacing = 10;
Widows_Report.margins = 16;

var panel1 = Widows_Report.add("panel", undefined, "Select the pages you want to search");
panel1.orientation = "column";
panel1.alignChildren = ["center", "center"];
panel1.spacing = 10;
panel1.margins = [10, 10, 9, 10];

var Page_Input = panel1.add("group");
Page_Input.orientation = "row";
Page_Input.alignChildren = ["center", "center"];
Page_Input.spacing = 10;
Page_Input.margins = 6;

var edittext1 = Page_Input.add('edittext', undefined, undefined, {name: "edittext1"});
edittext1.helpTip = "Enter the page number where you want the search to start";
edittext1.preferredSize.width = 45;
edittext1.preferredSize.height = 23;

var statictext1 = Page_Input.add("statictext", undefined, "Thru");
statictext1.preferredSize.width = 52;
statictext1.preferredSize.height = 17;
statictext1.justify = "center";

var edittext2 = Page_Input.add('edittext', undefined, undefined, {name: "edittext2"});
edittext2.helpTip = "Enter the page number where you want the search to end";
edittext2.preferredSize.width = 45;
edittext2.preferredSize.height = 23;

var group2 = Widows_Report.add("group");
group2.orientation = "column";
group2.alignChildren = ["left", "center"];
group2.spacing = 10;
group2.margins = 1;

var group3 = group2.add("group");
group3.orientation = "row";
group3.alignChildren = ["center", "top"];
group3.spacing = 10;
group3.margins = 0;

var button1 = group3.add("button", undefined, "Start");
button1.preferredSize.width = 68;

var button2 = group3.add("button", undefined, "Close");
button2.preferredSize.width = 61;

var group4 = group2.add("group");
group4.orientation = "column";
group4.alignChildren = ["center", "bottom"];
group4.spacing = 12;
group4.margins = 5;

// the text area for the report
var group5 = group2.add("group");
group5.orientation = "column";
group5.alignChildren = ["center", "bottom"];
group5.spacing = 1;
group5.margins = 1;

var text_area_w = 300;
var text_area_h = 600;
var text_area = group5.add("edittext", [10, 16, text_area_w - 16, text_area_h - 20], " ", {multiline: true, wantReturn: true});

// Start Button Click Event
button1.onClick = function() {
    var startPage = parseInt(edittext1.text);
    var endPage = parseInt(edittext2.text);

    // Validate page numbers
    if (isNaN(startPage) || isNaN(endPage) || startPage < 1 || startPage > app.activeDocument.pages.length || endPage < 1 || endPage > app.activeDocument.pages.length || startPage > endPage) {
        alert("Invalid page numbers. Please enter valid page numbers.");
    } else {
        var reportWidow = "HERE ARE YOUR RESULTS:\nThese pages have widows\n\n_______________________\n\n";

        for (var i = startPage - 1; i < endPage; i++) {
            var page = app.activeDocument.pages[i];
            var textFrames = page.textFrames;
            for (var j = 0; j < textFrames.length; j++) {
                var textFrame = textFrames[j];
                var paragraphs = textFrame.paragraphs;
                for (var k = 0; k < paragraphs.length; k++) {
                    var paragraph = paragraphs[k];
                    var fontSize = paragraph.pointSize;
                    if (fontSize >= 9.5 && fontSize <= 11) {
                        var lastLine = paragraph.lines[-1];
                        if (lastLine && lastLine.words.length === 1) {
                            reportWidow += "PAGE " + (i + 1) + ",     PARAGRAPH " + (k + 1) + "\r";
                                reportWidow += lastLine.words[0].contents + "\r\r";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        if (reportWidow !== "HERE ARE YOUR RESULTS:\n") {
            text_area.text = reportWidow; // <------------------ HERE
        } else {
            alert("Congratulations, No Widows Were Found!");
        }
    }
};

// Close Button Click Event
button2.onClick = function() {
    Widows_Report.close();
};

Widows_Report.show();



Wow @Yuri, Thank you so much for your answer and all of the time you dedicated to answering my question! I am so new to coding and still trying to learn all the terminology, characters and how to use them properly. People like yourself, who want to see others succeed at coding, are the ones that help people like me learn more and get excited to code more! Thanks, again -Bryan

You're welcome. Let me know if you need more help. I love to code and it's pleasure to me to share my humble knowledge with anyone. By the way, as far as I know, a 'widow' it's a lone line at the top of a page. And there are 'orphans', lone lines at the bottom of the page (a first line of a paragraph from the next page). I don't know what the name of these short lines at the end of paragraphs. @cybernetic.nomad calls them 'stubs' and it sounds good )

Yeah there has always been a bit of confusion in the Typography world between Orphans and Widows. My company calls the last line single word a Widow. However, it seems after a quick search (for the 238,457 time in my life) a word that sits alone at the end of a paragraph is called a RUNT.
The Chicago Manual of Style:
Widow: A paragraph-ending line that falls at the beginning of the following page.
Orphan: A paragraph-opening line that appears by itself at the bottom of a page or column.
Runt: Single, short word at the end of a paragraph.

one more question @yuri : In my search results window, how can I make the word that is considered a runt show in a bold text. I'd like the word to jump out as the user is making corrections.

It depends on what you mean. If you mean to make the 'runts' bold within the palette text area — I believe it's impossible. It's just a text. Probably it can be uppercased though. If you mean to make the 'runts' bold in the layout it can be done. Hypothetically there can be the way more complex interface where for every 'runt' will be created a button, and you jump to the 'runt' on the page as you press the button. But this is a quite task.

Something like this: https://i.sstatic.net/Wnw5E.png

Thanks a lot. yeah, I think my team can just work with what I've made so far. maybe when I learn more I can add in the Jump to Word option. Thanks again for all your help.
